# SWING is sometimes faster than openGL

Tags: java, swing, opengl, lwjgl

I wanted to figure out what is difference between openGL(LWJGL) and swing when it comes to rendering simple squares. Unsurprisingly, openGL won, but at some tests the result was close, or even in favor to swing. Why is it so??

My test results:

```
Testing for a total of 500000 rectangles
Swing time: 0.16367821
OpenGL time: 0.06317429
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  159.0899%

Testing for a total of 750000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.066062525
Swing time: 0.16988374
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  157.156%

Testing for a total of 1000000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.0907693
Swing time: 0.15694521
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  72.90561%

Testing for a total of 1250000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.09591239
Swing time: 0.17011923
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  77.369385%

Testing for a total of 1500000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.11926948
Swing time: 0.21623997
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  81.303696%

Testing for a total of 1750000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.16327758
Swing time: 0.25741237
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  57.65323%

Testing for a total of 2000000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.17265266
Swing time: 0.2788536
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  61.511322%

Testing for a total of 2250000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.2492242
Swing time: 0.3022127
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  21.261368%

Testing for a total of 2500000 rectangles
Swing time: 0.3231118
OpenGL time: 0.29499054
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  9.532944%

Testing for a total of 2750000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.34329778
Swing time: 0.38381234
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  11.801575%

Testing for a total of 3000000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.34859535
Swing time: 0.39274055
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  12.663734%

Testing for a total of 3250000 rectangles
Swing time: 0.4241282
OpenGL time: 0.44056854
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  -3.7316208%

Testing for a total of 3500000 rectangles
Swing time: 0.4600469
OpenGL time: 0.4737318
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  -2.8887482%

Testing for a total of 3750000 rectangles
Swing time: 0.40855232
OpenGL time: 0.25052726
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  63.07698%

Testing for a total of 4000000 rectangles
Swing time: 0.5119725
OpenGL time: 0.55266017
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  -7.362152%

Testing for a total of 4250000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.5010328
Swing time: 0.57198834
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  14.16185%

Testing for a total of 4500000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.53123826
Swing time: 0.5992712
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  12.806473%

Testing for a total of 4750000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.5412617
Swing time: 0.6458795
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  19.328514%

Testing for a total of 5000000 rectangles
OpenGL time: 0.58324844
Swing time: 0.69343716
OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  18.892242%
```

Code I was using:

```
package swingVSopengl;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class SwingVsOpenGL {

    static int amount = 0;
    static float swingtime, opengltime;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (amount = 500000; amount <= 5000000; amount += 250000) {

            System.out.println("Testing for a total of "
                    + String.valueOf(amount) + " rectangles");
            new SwingWay();
            new OpenGLWay();
            System.out.println("OpenGL relative to SWING is faster by  "
                    + String.valueOf(swingtime / opengltime * 100 - 100) + "%");
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static class SwingWay extends JFrame {

        public SwingWay() {
            setSize(64, 64);
            add(new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public void paint(Graphics g) {
                    super.paint(g);
                    long time = System.nanoTime();
                    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                        g.fillRect(0, 0, 16, 16);
                    }
                    swingtime = (float) (System.nanoTime() - time) / 1000000000;
                    System.out.print("Swing time: ");
                    System.out.println(swingtime);
                    dispose();
                }
            });
            setVisible(true);
        }

    }

    private static class OpenGLWay {
        OpenGLWay() {
            try {
                Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(64, 64));
                Display.setTitle("A fresh display!");
                Display.create();
            } catch (LWJGLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(1);
            }

            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

            long time = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glVertex2i(0, 0);
                glVertex2i(16, 0);
                glVertex2i(16, 16);
                glVertex2i(0, 16);
                glEnd();
            }
            opengltime = (float) (System.nanoTime() - time) / 1000000000;
            System.out.print("OpenGL time: ");
            System.out.println(opengltime);

            Display.destroy();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rendering a single square is not very difficult. Essentially it boils down to windowing a piece of memory and filling it with a specific value.

Also the way you use OpenGL suffers from huge amounts of overhead. What you're measuring is not the efficiency of SWING vs. OpenGL, but the efficiency at making function calls. Ditch `glBegin` … `glEnd` (they've been out of fashion for over 15 years now) and use vertex arrays. Also don't starve the GPU by spoon feeding it with drawing commands. Instead offer it an All-You-Can-Eat by means of vertex arrays of at least 100 primitives per drawing batch. Only then you're getting out of overhead-land.

Comment: Beyond this, the code is also not measuring the rendering time. There would need to be at least a `glFinish()` at the end, otherwise it's only measuring the time for queuing up the commands, not for doing any rendering.